What then is logic if there are different logics?
If, as many if not most academics seem to insist, there are different logics, each one they regard as perfectly legitimate but best for only certain categories of problems, then what is logic according to them?
Thank you to quote the relevant authors.

I consider logic a collection of different axiomatized theories to formalize truth and falseness of propositions, implication, proof etc. The situation is similar with other axiomatized theories, e.g., geometry and set theory. - If I remember correctly you and I had a previous discussion on this subject, without agreement.

There's yet another minimal logic which is supposed to be the largest common denominator of all your concerned logics...

@JoWehler "I consider logic a collection of different axiomatized theories" You really believe that this is what logicians since Aristotle had in mind when they talked of logic? That logic was a collection of different axiomatized theories?

@DoubleKnot "There's yet another minimal logic which is supposed to be the largest common denominator of all your concerned logics" Does that make it logic? I don't know what could be the value of being the common denominator of theories which are not theories of logic.

The second sentence there already claims It is an intuitionistic and paraconsistent logic,...

@Speakpigeon I told you what I consider the actual(!) assessment of logic. It has changed since the days of Aristotle. That's an example of progress in formal sciences.

@JoWehler How do you know it is "progress", not regress?

@Speakpigeon Because we today can look back to the whole development and assess the reason for the single steps. Aristotle could not look forward.

"Logics are theories of validity: they tell us which argument forms are valid. Different logics disagree about which forms are valid... If there were more than one property of validity (and so more than one interpretation of “valid”) where one of the logics captures validity in one sense, while its rival captures validity in another... If one wants to study vagueness, the correct logic might be one that allows for intermediate truth-values... Since the correct model is goal-relative, so is the correct logic." SEP, Logical Pluralism

See here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-ontology/#DiffConcLogi

@JoWehler "Because we today can look back to the whole development and assess the reason for the single steps. Aristotle could not look forward." I don't know what that means except we are right you are wrong.

It means: We know why(!) the hitherto existing approach had to be improved.

@Speakpigeon There you go again In what way are Classical Logic, Intuitionistic Logic, Minimal Logic, and all those in-between not theories of logic? In particular, Intuitionism and Clasical Logic have explicit meanings and uses.

Minimal logic as the common denominator of theories of logic has some extremely nice bidirectional implication Heyting lattice and categorical left/right joins properties thus holds one of the keys to a more general categorical logic understanding, IIRC Kristian Berry once posted a question about it about one year ago with scholarly references...

Maybe the issue is that of a "natural" (human) logical faculty vs different implementations of it. Compare with a (possible) natural language faculty vs different human languages.

@JoWehler "It means: We know why(!) the hitherto existing approach had to be improved." No you don't. Would-be modern logicians maybe believed they had a good reason (and they sure knew it), but their reason is junk so they didn't actually  know that the Aristotelian definition of logical validity had to be replaced.

@MauroALLEGRANZA "a "natural" (human) logical faculty vs different implementations of it." Precisely, logic is rather obviously not like language. Humans speak different languages and they have to learn their mother tongue. But they don't have different logics and they don't have to learn the one logic that they have.

At the object language level, there are of course various logics: classical logic, intuitionistic logic, etc.  At the level of metamathematics, Abraham Robinson argues that a researcher falls back on classical logic (incorporating the principle of excluded middle):

"It seems to me that the rules of logic and of certain parts
of Arithmetic which are used in the analysis of a formal theory are by no
means arbitrary.  For example, even when considering some non-standard,
e.g., three-valued, logic, the logician ultimately assumes that a given concrete
situation either obtains or does not obtain, and that these possibilities
are mutually exclusive. In other words, at this point the logician actually
uses two-valued prepositional logic or, in syntactical terms, he assumes the
law of contradiction, not-(X and not-X), and the law of the excluded
middle, X or not-X."

This is on page 237 in

Robinson, Abraham.  Formalism 64. Logic, Methodology and Philos. Sci. (Proc. 1964 Internat. Congr.), pp. 228–246, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1965.


That’s not entirely true. Constructive mathematicians are pretty good at defining things without any recourse to Classical Logic. I would bet some relevance logicians have done the same.

@PW_246 I think the author rightfully insists not that classical logic is binding, but that it is intuitive, and rightly so. It takes a great deal of education to escape the intuitive perception that there are Laws of Thought.

Logic is the study of what follows from what.
There are different logics because there are different answers to that question.
And there are several different accounts of why there are different answers to that question.
The SEP has a good introduction to the subject. Some other useful texts are Stewart Shapiro, Varieties of Logic, Oxford 2014; Susan Haack, Deviant Logic, Cambridge, 1974; Beall and Restall, Logical Pluralism, Oxford, 2006.

Is there a meta-logic that governs the study of different logics?

@Barmar Many theorists consider classical logic to be the natural choice of logic at the metalanguage level. But it is not the only position. There is some discussion of it in the SEP article.
